# Sending bean data to javascript method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to pass bean values to javascript code after ajax update but it doesn't work.

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{bean.transactionStarted}" onclick="userclicked(xhr,args,status)"/>
```

And the backing bean adds the value via:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam("message", "message");
```

When I debug I am seeing upper statement executed correctly but it does not arrive to js and it is not alerting:

```
function userclicked(xhr, status, args) {
    alert(args.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `onclick` was called before backing `bean` method completed. You should wait until it finishes. Use `oncomplete`, as follows:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.transactionStarted}" oncomplete="userclicked(xhr,args,status)"/>
```

Comment: `oncomplete` is the right attribute, but not sure if xhr is a known js variable in that moment (similar for other parameters).